# Cannot understand preg_match pattern

Tags: php, regex

Please explain to me when `$string` will be `true`. I cannot find all information by Google.

```
 preg_match('#^[0-9a-f]{32}$#', $string)
```

`{32}` means `$string` must contain 32 chars? `[0-9a-f]` is mean that only numeric and lower case must be in `$string`?

I have validation where I check if `preg_match` is `true`. But I cannot understand `$string` template.

Comment: I suggest you take a look into the functions documentation (which is always the first place you should look, _before_ google): http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: The regular expression validates a 32 digit hexadecimal number, I'd say.

Comment: If $string is a string containing exactly 32 hexadecimal digits in lower case, such as `0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef`, then the ` preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{32}$/', $string)` will return true. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Not sure but, the begin/end of string anchors `^$` might not be necessary in preg_match() if the regex implicitly must match the entire string. Sort of like a test. The find function should find sub strings I think.

Answer (score 0):

`$string` is the subject you are searching on.

```
$pattern = '/0x[\da-f]/i';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Read the docs.  As for return values of this function, if you just care for existence of a match...

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't use the # symbol for regex, you need a forward slash.  I have:

`if(preg_match("/[^0-9]/", $data)){$data=null}`

This will evaluate if the input data is a number.  There is A LOT you can do with regex ... what is it you need to do?  Perhaps a more specific question about what you need it to do and what you have tried?

Comment: I used to use `#` as a delimiter all the time.  Not an issue,  php.net uses it extensively.

Comment: if (!preg_match('#^[0-9a-f]{32}$#', $model->$attribute)) {
            $this->addError($model, $attribute, 'Invalid image id');
        },    always get INVALID IMAGE ID

Comment: @Dreamwalker *"learn something new everday!"* - That's the beauty of Stack ;-) I too didn't know that some time ago.

Comment: @user3054630 Are you trying to check a filename a user submits?